# Why is there no sweet (as in 'with sugar') butter?

Tags: butter

I understand salted butter can be useful is some situations, but why there's no such thing as "sugar butter" that can be sold in stores? I mean, there is sweet milk (concentrated, for instance) and sweet yoghurt, but no sweet butter nor sweet cheese. Is it just cultural or is there some chemical explanation behind it?

Comment: Regardless of the butter discussion, there ARE a number of sweet cheeses. White stilton and carre frais are relatively sweet, to say nothing of mascarpone or gjetost.

Comment: I was actually thinking about cheese that have sugar added during the fabrication process - but I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: @heathenJesus: When you say "gjetost", do you mean as in brown goat cheese? "gjetost" sounds quite similar to "geitost", which is Norwegian for "goat cheese", and is a sweet goat cheese that gets brown color because of the sweetness. This is a special Norwegian cheese.

Comment: @awe: yes, the brown cheese that is sweet because of the carmelization. Gjetost/geitost/brunost/mesost/mysustor/myseost/braunkäse are all different names for the same type of cheese.

Comment: It might be against local food laws, and in some case require the concoction to be sold under a different name than "butter", to prevent adulteration of sub-par butter...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Butter traditionally has salt in it as a preservative, mainly to stop bacterial growth on the residual whey, and to slow fat rancidity

Modern butter has a much lower amount of salt than is required for shelf storage in the pre-electric era. Now we have refrigerators, salt is not required at such a high level

Butter with no salt has nearly half of the shelf life of modern salted butter

Processed sugar is a modern ingredient, and therefore there is no culture in having it in butter.

Sweet yoghurt and milk are all "new" inventions

Using salt as a preservative is as old as recorded history. Many cultures used salt to preserve fruits, as well as meats and vegetables

Comment: Which problems are caused by processed sugar?

Comment: @BaffledCook Processed sugar is a key ingredient to producing tasty packaged and processed foods, most of which are high GI index foods  (high fat, empty carbs etc), and are bad for pre-diabetics, and may lead to type II diabetes. Removing sugar makes large parts of this food group much less appealing and "addictive"

Comment: Could sugar have some preserving effect as well? Such as in applesauce? Or is it just the removal of water that actually helps conserving it? I was thinking if, at least chemically, such a "sweet butter" could be meaningful.

Comment: Just to add another thought that led me to my question, I often see tomato sauce as having both salt and sugar added to it, and I thought both would help conserve it. Besides, tomato is an example of something that can be made both sweet (as juice) and salty (as sauce), so I considered generalizing it to other things such as butter: why not some sugar butter for people who love their popcorn both sweet and buttered?

Comment: @dhekir: sugar in tomato sauce is usually put to counteract the acidity of the tomato.

Comment: Health/nutrition problems, real though they may be, are off-topic. It'd be fine in this case if the answer were "sweet butter doesn't exist because it'd be too unhealthy so no one makes/wants it", but I don't think that's what you're saying here.

Comment: @dhekir this is actually a different discussion, but yes, you can preserve with sugar alone, as long as the concentration is high enough to interfere with the bacterial physiology through osmosis. Old-time preserves were durable without pasterization, because the sugar content was high enough. But most foods never reach the sugar concentration needed for preservation, certainly not ketchup.

Comment: @dhekir, the keywords for what rumtscho has described are "available water" and "water activity". Reducing AW is a crucial part of food preservation. Pectin and sugar both act in fruit preserves to reduce the water that is "free" for use by organisms.

Comment: Part of the reason we don't see sweet butter products is that the USDA/FDA guidelines for butter allow for the addition of salt, but do not allow for additional sugar, and require a minimum of 80% milk fat content.  Yogurt regulations, on the other hand, have all of their requirements for milk fat, milk solids, acidity, etc based on the product prior to addition of bulk flavoring agents, colorings, or additional ingredients such as fruits.  In order to make sweet butter that is still 80% milk fat, some or all of the milk solids and water would need to be replaced by sugar.

Comment: downvoted for editorial content that had nothing to do with OP's question

Comment: @sarge_smith What content is that? Fell free to edit or answer yourself :-)

Comment: @Didgeridrew We have no idea if the OP lives in the USA, so the USDA/FDA guidelines may not mean much to them. Many "western" countries have similar butter laws, but this is far from universal

Comment: @TFD I understand that the OP may not be in the US, but they did not list a location in their profile.  The USDA/FDA guidelines in this case follow the WHO and FAO CODEX Alimentarius' international food standards supported by 184 member nations plus the EU.

Answer (score 8):

There is such a thing, for example Corriher has a great recipe in Cookwise for chambord butter. These foods are of course not pure butter, just as "fruit yoghurt" is not pure yogurt: you can mix butter with sugar and sweet flavorings to make a sweet butter spread, like you can mix it with parsley and chives to make a savory spread.

As to why there is no commercially mixed sweet butter readily available, I suspect that this is a simple case of the law of supply and demand. And the missing demand for certain foods globally (like sweet butter) or locally (like cream of tartar) is an interesting sociology problem (I suspect it is due to the cooking styles in certain influential books like Better Homes and Gardens in the US and Dr Oetker Kochbuch in Germany), but it has no real culinary roots.

Comment: It is commercially available, although very localized. Sweet butter from Soria (Spain). Some links: [Spanish Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantequilla_de_Soria) and its [DOC](http://www.mantequilladesoria.com/content/view/12/46/). The links are in Spanish; as I said it's very localized.

Answer (score 0):

Bacteria loves sugar. Butter with sugar added will spoil in a few hours at room temperature unless preservatives are added.

Comment: What's your source for this?

Comment: Sugar in sufficient amount tends to act as a preservative (think jam, syrup, and marmalade), similar to salt (in one case the bacteria get candied, macerated and/or die from diabetes, in the other case they get salt cured ;) ). What thrives on sugar, however, is mold (which is what eventually gets jams and syrups stored at room temperature) - but I don't think it likes substrates as rich in fat as butter...

Answer (score -1):

Two reasons.
Butter is sweet.
Butter is a base ingredient.  How would one determine the level of sweetness and what would it be used for. How would sweet butter increase sales over plain?

Comment: Sweetened condensed milk as mentioned in the question is of a standardized sweetness, and it sells well because there are plenty of things you can easily make with it. I think it's fair to ask why the same thing didn't happen with butter.

Comment: Try some raw unsweetened butter from a farm. Butter from the store is sweet

Comment: I'm not sure what store butter you've had, but the stuff I buy has zero grams of sugar, and it doesn't have sugar as an ingredient. Maybe it naturally has a very slightly sweet taste, but this is definitely not what the OP's talking about. (For example, sweetened condensed milk is a little over half sugar by weight.)